# can't add multiple ftp site with host name in iis

Tags: iis, ftp

I have 2 ftp server clustered with load balance and seen with a virtual ip.

```
ftp server a : x.x.x.5
ftp server b : x.x.x.6
ftp virtual ip : x.x.x.10
```

And i have 2 file server that is load balanced as well. I want to add multi ftp sites in iis with one ip and one port but with different urls that are defined in a dns server in my network.

But when I add ftp with url it doesn't open and just opens the default ftp with x.x.x.10 url.

What am I doing wrong?

How i can have multi ftp with one ip and one port in iis

Comment: This is only possible in iis 7.5 and above, as you need host name support from what I can tell

Comment: i use iis 8 , i use host name when add ftp site but my problem don't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to configure the FTP Sites in IIS with host headers that match the urls that you're using.

What version of IIS are you using?  Also, you may have issues if you're trying to host these for sites with Secure Ftp.

If you're just doing regular for you should be able to do it with host headers though.

Comment: i use iis 8. how to configure the FTP Sites in IIS with host headers?

Comment: Sorry - I totally misted this update.  It's under bindings.  Click "Enable Virtual Host Names", and then type the dns name that you want to bind to on each ftp site.

Comment: i enabled virtual host names and type dns name and different path location , i define this for 2 ftp but both of two ftp open same default file location.

Comment: Looks like you have to include the target dns name in the username field as well:   www.domain.com|MyUser and then the password for MyUser.  I'm not sure why that's necessary, but it appears to be.  http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/using-ftp-virtual-host-names-in-iis-7